# Power of Uniform Order Statistics

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution, beta-distribution, order-statistics, dirichlet-distribution

I know that if $U$ is a uniform r.v. in $(0,1)$, then $U^a\sim Beta(1/a,1)$ with $a>0$.

On the other hand, if $U_{(1)}\leq \cdots\leq U_{(n)}$ are the uniform order statistics, then, with $U_{(0)}=0$ and $U_{(n+1)}=1$, we have
$$(U_{(i+1)}-U_{(i)})_{i=0\ldots n}\sim Dir(1,\ldots,1)$$

My question is: Can we say something like
$$(U_{(i+1)}^a-U_{(i)}^a)_{i=0\ldots n}\sim Dir(1/a,\ldots,1/a,1) ?$$

Comment: I have edited your question to introduce more subscript brackets and other minor adjustments.  You might want to check it is what you want

Comment: $Dir(1/a,\ldots,1/a)$ is certainly not correct as that would make $\mathbb E (U_{(i+1)}^a-U_{(i)}^a) = \frac1{n+1}$ when these expectations will vary with both $a$ and $i$

Comment: $Dir(1/a,\ldots,1/a,1)$ will also be wrong

Comment: Is there some particular reason ?

Comment: If $n$ and $a$ are both large, then the expectations will strictly increase with $i$ while they do not for that Dirichlet distribution

Comment: Why it should increase with i ?

Comment: Because with $a>1$ the $U_{(i)}^a$ will get smaller than $U_{(i)}$ and so the gaps $U_{(i+1)}^a-U_{(i)}^a$ will tend to be smaller for low $i$ than for high $i$

Comment: Looking at some simulation, I suspect that you may be able to say $U_{(i+1)}^a-U_{(i)}^a$ has a Beta distribution, but I am more doubtful about the joint distribution being Dirichlet.  I may be wrong

Comment: @Henry I don’t get why it will tend to be smaller for low i

Comment: Try it and see.  I suspect if $a$ is an integer then $\mathbb E\left[U_{(i+1)}^a-U_{(i)}^a\right]$ may be $\dfrac{i+a-1 \choose i}{n+a \choose n}$ which is clearly increasing as $i$ increases.

Comment: As the expectation of $U_{(i)}^a$ is $i/(n+a)$, we have that the obtained expectation do not depend on $i$

Comment: Why do you think the expectation of $U_{(i)}^a$ is $i/(n+a)$?   For example if $a=2$ and $n=2$ and $i=1$ it is $\frac16$ not $\frac14$ and I think in general is similar ratio of binomial coefficients $\dfrac{i+a-1 \choose i-1}{n+a \choose n}$

Comment: You are right..